# Корректно ли словосочетание «швейное рукоделие»

Tags: грамотная-речь

Будет ли ошибкой словосочетание «швейное рукоделие»: «Я открыла для себя волшебный  мир швейного рукоделия»?

Если нет, то каким словосочетанием можно было бы заменить?

P.S. Прошу прощения, впервые на сайте, не совсем разобралась как поблагодарить высокой оценкой отвечающих

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Корректно, изменений не требуется. А совершенствоваться, как известно, можно до бесконечности.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Калмыцко-китайские отношения в XVIII веке](https://books.google.ru/books?id=fVhGAQAAIAAJ&q=%D0%A8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE.%20%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B5&dq=%D0%A8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%D1%85%20%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B9%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%88%D0%B5%20%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE.%20%D0%9C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B5&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj3nJTEzcjgAhWMUJoKHS0MB3EQ6AEIKTAA)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Памятники письменности Востока](https://books.google.ru/books?id=SHlkgK_nwo8C&q=%D0%A8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5&dq=%D0%A8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5%20%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B5&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwisjZCZz8jgAhUks4sKHYJQA0UQ6AEITTAG)

---

[Я и не задумывалась раньше, что для швейного рукоделия придумано
столько мелочей.](https://books.google.ru/books?id=V95nBgAAQBAJ&pg=PT40&dq=%D0%AF%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5,%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D1%88%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjLmYnYzsjgAhWmmIsKHTjRDwwQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%D0%AF%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BD%D0%B5%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F%20%D1%88%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%20%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%8F%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BE&f=false)

Comment: Очень здорово, что есть ссылки с подтверждением, огромное спасибо за помощь!

Comment: На этом сайте "спасибо" заменяется кликом по верхнему треугольнику, а помогший ответ - по галочке внизу возле ответа.

Answer (score 1):

Есть термины белошвейное мастерство и золотошвейное и белошвейное производство, — кружевоплетение (игольное, петельным швом, вязанное крючком, на спицах и на коклюшах, фриволите), а макже вышивка (крестом, гладью, тамбурным швом, мережка, филейно-гипюрная вышивка).

Я бы остановился на варианте: «Я открыла для себя волшебный мир белошвейного дела».

Comment: Прекрасный термин. Спасибо большое!!